# cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not called in UITableViewController class

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

Here is the code that I have used to reload my table. I am trying to display facebook friends list into this tableview, once I got the list I am posting notification to this class there I am trying reloding the tableview.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable) name:@"reload" object:nil];

- (void)reloadTable
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

all other methods are getting called but only `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called.

Comment: Check your IBOutlet... and make sure `- (void)reloadTable` is called

Comment: Is `numberOfRowsInSection:` one of the ones being called?  If so, what value is it returning?

Comment: is the class with cellForRowAtIndexPath method the correct delegate of self.tableView?

Comment: @Maulik Outlet is connected properly and reloadTable is getting called.

Comment: @meronix Yes it is correct method of tableview (not delegae, datasource method).

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes numberOfRowsInSection & numberOfSectionsInTableView 1 and 1.